# Vue JS: Pull data into a drop-down from a local js file

Tags: vue.js

I have a VueJs component, the data was originally on the page which worked well. It populated 3 drop-down menus. I want to move the data to a separate file hosted locally but I cant seem to get it to populate the drop-down menus. At the moment the first drop-down menu only displays the text 'data' which is the text from the top of the JS file. How do I get it to pull in all the data please? Any help is appreciated!

One of the select menus:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
      <span>Subject one</span>
      <select v-model="selectedSubjectone">
        <option value="">Select subject one</option>
        <option
          v-for="(subjectone_obj, subjectone) in hass"
          :value="subjectone"
          :key="subjectone"
          >{{ subjectone }}</option
        >
      </select>
    </div>
```

Some of the code in the script:

```
<script>
import hass from "../assets/hass-subject-combination-data";

export default {
  name: "HassSubjectsCombinations",

  props: {
    msg: String,
  },

  data: function() {
    return {
      hass,
      subjecttwo: [],
      subjectsthree: [],
      selectedSubjectone: "",
      selectedSubjecttwo: "",
      selectedSubjectthree: "",
    };
  },
```

The start of the JS file containing the data:

```
export default {
      data() {
        return {
          //data created in July 2021
          hass: {
            //First choice in the dropdown select menu is Economics in this example
            Economics: {
              //Second choice under Economics is Eduction in this example
              Education: [
                //Third choices under Economics & Eduction. The rest follows the same pattern 1st, 2nd, 3rd choices with the three drop-down select menus
                "English",
                "English & Creative Writing ",
                "French",
                "History",
                "Journalism, Media & Communication",
                "Law",
                "Politics & International Relations",
                "Psychology",
                "Social Policy",
                "Spanish",
              ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the JS file, remove the data object and export a normal object that contains your data.

After that, import that object in the component and add a computed method that will return it.

JS file -

```
         export default {
        //First choice in the dropdown select menu is Economics in this example
        Economics: {
          //Second choice under Economics is Eduction in this example
          Education: [
            //Third choices under Economics & Eduction. The rest follows the same pattern 1st, 2nd, 3rd choices with the three drop-down select menus
            "English",
            "English & Creative Writing ",
            "French",
            "History",
            "Journalism, Media & Communication",
            "Law",
            "Politics & International Relations",
            "Psychology",
            "Social Policy",
            "Spanish",
          ]}}
```

Component -

```
     <script>
import hass from "../assets/hass-subject-combination-data";

export default {
  name: "HassSubjectsCombinations",

  props: {
    msg: String,
  },

  data: function() {
    return {
      subjecttwo: [],
      subjectsthree: [],
      selectedSubjectone: "",
      selectedSubjecttwo: "",
      selectedSubjectthree: "",
    };
  },
computed: {
hassData () {
return hass
}
```

Now use `hassData` inside the template and it should contains the imported object.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I should have worked this out myself. Thanks for taking the time to help. Appreciated!